# ArrayFormula, RegexExtract, and Join in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data set wherein emails are populated. I would like to list all the surnames extracted in the emails per cell and will be all joined to a one single cell but I want to put a separator or delimeter to the emails obtaine per cell.

Here is the data set:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| john.smith@gmail.com, jane.doe@gmail.com | UPDATE |
| john.smith@gmail.com | CLOSE |

And here is the formula to extract

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 PROPER(
  REGEXEXTRACT( 
   A:A, 
   REGEXREPLACE(
    A:A,
    "(\w+)@","($1)@"
   )
  )
 )
)
```

This initially yields the ff:

| C | D |
| --- | --- |
| Smith | Doe |
| Smith |  |

I would like to use `JOIN()` inside the `ARRAYFORMULA()` but it is not working as I seem to think it would since it outputs an error that it only accepts one row or one column of data. My initial understanding of `ARRAYFORMULA()` is that it iterates through the course of the data, so I thought it will `JOIN()` first, and then move on to the next element/row but I guess it doesn't work that way. I can use `FLATTEN()` but I want to have delimiters or separators in between the row elements. I need help in obtaining my intended final result which will look like this:

```
UPDATE:
Smith
Doe

CLOSE:
Smith
```

All are located in one cell, C1. UPDATE and CLOSE are from column B.
EDIT: I would like to clarify that the email entries in column A are dynamic and maybe more than two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
=arrayformula(flatten(if(A2:A<>"",regexreplace(trim(split(B2:B&":"&char(9999)&regexreplace(Proper(A2:A),"@[\w\.]+,\ ?|@.*",char(9999)&" "),char(9999))),".*\.",),)))
```

[image]

**NOTES:**

`Proper(A2:A)` changes the capitalisation.

The regexreplace `"@[\w\.]+,\ ?|@.*"` finds:

`@` symbol...

then any number of `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `_` [using \w] or `.` [using \.]

then a comma

then 'optionally' a space `\`  [the optional bit is `?`]

or [using `|`], the `@` symbol then an number of characters [using `.*`]

The result is replaced with a character that you won't expect to have in your text - `char(9999)` which is a pencil icon, and a trailing space (used later on when the flatten keeps a gap between lines). The purpose is to get all of the 'name.surname' and 'nameonly' values in front of any `@` symbol and separate them with `char(9999)`.

[image]

Then infront of the regexreplace is `B2:B&":"&char(9999)&` which gets the value from column B, the `:` chanracter and `char(9999)`.

[image]

The `split()` function then separates then into columns. `Trim()` is used to get rid of spaces in front of names that don't contain `.`.

[image]

The next `regexreplace()` function deletes anything before, and including `.` to keep surname or name without `.`.

[image]

The `if(A2:A<>""` only process rows where there is a value in col A. The `arrayformula()` function is required to cascade the formula down the sheet.

I didn't output the results in a single cell, but it looks like you've sorted that with textjoin.

Here's my version of getting the results into a single cell.

```
=arrayformula(textjoin(char(10),1,if(A2:A<>"",REGEXREPLACE(B2:B&":"&char(10)&regexreplace(Proper(A2:A),"@[\w\.]+,\ ?|@.*",char(10)),".*\.",),)))
```

[image]

Comment: This actually worked perfectly and is easy to understand. Using `TEXTJOIN()` to combined the whole thing in one cell. 

I just have some questions in `REGEXREPLACE` . When disecting the formula, this formula:
`=regexreplace(Proper(A:A),"@[\w\.]+,\ ?|@.*",char(9999)&" ")`

Only outputs only the first element in A1, i.e.
`John.Smith✏`

But when `SPLIT()`, all the captures are shown including `Jane. Doe` in one of the columns.
And then when the First Names and the . is removed using `REGEXREPLACE()', the output is only `:` for some reason.

Is this some sort bug?

Comment: Also, why is `char(9999)` used? And an interesting thing I've noted is that using `JOIN()` instead of `TEXTJOIN()` outputs an error with characters exceeding the 50000 limit for some reason.

Comment: I've added notes to try and explain what's going on.

Comment: I've realized my mistakes in the use of the range `A:A` or element since it refers to the same row when used in a formula. The reason that I was getting the outputs I mentioned in the comments was I was plugging the formula in different rows from the existing row cells with contents. I forgot that `A:A` only becomes a dynamic range when it is used in conjunction functions such as `FILTER()` or in `ARRAYFORMULA()`. Thank you for explaining it thoroughly.

Comment: No problem - happy to help :-)  BTW, if you go to https://regexr.com/ and paste the regex expression there, you can hover over each element and it will explain what each item does - probably better than I can explain. You can then paste your content in the text area and see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your A:A cells will always contain *only* contiguous email addresses separated by commas, you could place this in, say, C1 (being sure that both Columns C and D are otherwise empty beforehand):

`=TRANSPOSE(FILTER({B:B,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(PROPER(A:A),","),"([^\.]+)@"))},A:A<>""))`

If this produces the desired result and you'd like to know how it works, report back. The first step, however, is to make sure it works as expected.

Comment: The result outputs multiple columns. Seems like it results to the column created by 'REGEXEXTRACT' with the headers of the items in Column B.

Comment: Yes. It's not clear from your comment whether or not this works for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({{B1; IF(B2:B="",,"×"&B2:B)}, 
 PROPER(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A, REGEXREPLACE(A:A, "(\w+)@", "($1)@")))})
 ,,9^9)),,9^9)), " |×", CHAR(10)))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly in the given data but will this work when the range of the emails and column B is expanded? I haven't fully analyzed yet your solution but there are elements such as B1 and B2. 

Will this work if it is in a Google Forms situation wheren the range is ever expanding?

Comment: Also in the application I'm intending to use it for, the range is dynamic (and hence the rows). The row number of column A and B will always be the same since the range is a FILTER for both  A and B with a similar search key in a different data column.